# except command seems to be not executed via ssh

Tags: expect

I learn how to use expect and I can't run any command (in this case pwd) in a remote host.

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh ibmcoll@192.168.1.100
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/home/ibmcoll/.ssh/id_rsa': "
send passphrase\r
expect "*ibmcoll*"
sleep 3
send "pwd\r"
sleep 3
send "exit\r"
```

output:

```
expect ssh.exp
spawn ssh ibmcoll@192.168.1.100
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ibmcoll/.ssh/id_rsa':
Last login: Sat Feb 11 19:10:47 2023 from servername
*(some welcome lines are here)*
[ibmcoll@servername ~]$
```

Where this script fails?

When run `expect -d script.sh` let me only post the most important part:

```
expect: does "\r\nLast login: Thu Feb 16 21:32:06 2023 from servername.domain\r\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n*         This system should be used for conducting ####### business                *\r\n*        or for purposes authorized by ####### management it is mandatory           *\r\n*     to comply with all the requirements listed in the applicable security policy  *\r\n*      and only process or store the data classes approved for this                 *\r\n*       asset type use is subject to audit at any time by ####### management        *\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n\u001b]0;ibmcoll@servername:~\u0007\u001b[?1034h[ibmcoll@servername ~]$ " 
(spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*ibmcoll*"? **yes**

expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\nLast login: Thu Feb 16 21:32:06 2023 from servername.domain\r\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n*         This system should be used for conducting ####### business                *\r\n*        or for purposes authorized by ####### management it is mandatory           *\r\n*     to comply with all the requirements listed in the applicable security policy  *\r\n*      and only process or store the data classes approved for this                 *\r\n*       asset type use is subject to audit at any time by ####### management        *\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n\u001b]0;ibmcoll@servername:~\u0007\u001b[?1034h[ibmcoll@servername ~]$ "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nLast login: Thu Feb 16 21:32:06 2023 from servername.domain\r\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n*         This system should be used for conducting ####### business                *\r\n*        or for purposes authorized by ####### management it is mandatory           *\r\n*     to comply with all the requirements listed in the applicable security policy  *\r\n*      and only process or store the data classes approved for this                 *\r\n*       asset type use is subject to audit at any time by ####### management        *\r\n************************************************************************************\r\n\u001b]0;ibmcoll@servername:~\u0007\u001b[?1034h[ibmcoll@servername ~]$ "

send: sending "pwd\r" to { exp4 }

send: sending "exit\r" to { exp4 }
```

Comment: after you `send` a command you need to wait for the shell prompt so you know the command has completed, just like when you manually interact with the program.

Comment: @sexpect-expect-for-shells I tried to use 'sleep' but it nothing changed.

Comment: please update your script and post new debug logs.

Comment: @sexpect I updated. When it comes to `sleep` I see that program stops for the given time.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I found that if I place `expect "*ibmcoll*"` after `send "pwd\r"` than the script works, even with no `sleep` commands. Why?

Comment: see my first comment. Expect is just simulating what a real person would do.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells yeah, so I added `sleep 3` to wait for the output. That did not help. But if 'sleep 3' is removed and script do `expect` once again than it works. I don't get it.

Comment: that's how Expect works. if you don't call `expect` you cannot see the output. you can try `expect -c 'spawn date; sleep 1'` and `expect -c 'spawn date; expect eof'` to see the difference.